# Selecting fields from polymorphic relationship in DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-relationship

I have an `Order` model with a polymorphic customer relationship to `Parent` and `School`. My goal now is to query the orders and generate a report including the `name` and `email` of the customer. Both `name` and `email` fields are present in `Parent` and `School`.

`Order` has:

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

`Parent` and `School` both have:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Order::class, 'customer');
}
```

My query currently is:

```
$result = Order::query()
        ->with('customer')
        ->select(
             'orders.id',
             'amount'
          )->get();

dd($result->first()->toArray());
```

Result is:

```
array:6 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "amount" => "42.00"
  "customer" => null
]
```

I thought it would be possible to add `customer.name` and `customer.email` in the list of selected fields but Eloquent complains that the customer field `customer.name` cannot be found which makes sense?

How do I obtain the data in the related models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Laravel 8, you can see the link [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-morph-to-relationships).

Then, your code would be:

```
$result = Order::whereHasMorph(
    'orderable', // this is your polymorphic relationship you define
    [Parent::class, School::class], // your list of Models you want to query from the polymorphic relationship
    function (Builder $query) {
        $query->select('name', 'email');
    }
)->get();
```

That should do it.

Comment: Only just back to looking at this. Thank you.